# Custom GeoServer rendering transformation

Tags: geoserver, wps, geoscript

Following on from my previous question [here](http://geoscript.org/groovy/api/geoscript/process/Process.html), I'm trying to create rendering transformation using the GeoScript Groovy API. I've got most of the code written but I can't figure out how to wrap it up for GeoServer to discover.

I've found the [process package](http://geoscript.org/groovy/api/geoscript/process/Process.html) in the GeoScript API but, to me, it looks like it's for an existing process. I've also looked at [this](https://boundlessgeo.com/2013/10/geoscript-in-action-part-2/) Python example, but the way the inputs and outputs are defined is different to Groovy. Could someone please provide a short example?